# Error: The method ofMonths(int) is undefined for the type Period

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method ofMonths(int) is undefined for the type Period

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 30);
    Period period = Period.ofMonths(1); // create a period
    performAnimalEnrichment(start, end, period);
}

private static void performAnimalEnrichment(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, Period period) { // uses the generic
                                                                                                // period
    LocalDate upTo = start;
    while (upTo.isBefore(end)) {
        System.out.println("give new toy: " + upTo);
        upTo = upTo.plus(period); // adds the period
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your import statements?

Comment: agree with matt, perhaps you have imported wrong library

Comment: `import java.time.Period` instead of `jdk.jfr.Period` (although the jdk/jfr one appears to be java 9).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's working!
import java.time.Period;
Import issue